# Drupal Features Path To Module

Tags: php, git, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to do versioning with GIT and I'm trying to figure out the features module. The Drupal configuration has all its modules stored in the site that it belongs so.

Ex with Google Maps:

```
sites/theme/modules/googlemaps
```

But I've been saving the features in the default all directory. Ex:

```
sites/all/modules/googlemaps
```

Should the googlemaps feature and module be stored in the same path? I ask because I noticed certain things don't seem to be refelected when pushed and pulled.And is there a good tutorial on how to use features with git?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal best practices encourage storing all non core modules in "sites/all/modules"

Only if you have a multi-site install and want to add a specific piece of code to one of the sites should you store something in "sites/sitename.com/modules".

As far as features go the modules directory doesn't care how you nest the modules as long as they are under the "sites/all/modules" directory. So you want to create 4 seperate directories to store your modules in:

"sites/all/modules/contrib" - this stores all downloaded community modules
"sites/all/modules/custom"  - this stores your custom modules
"sites/all/modules/features" - this stores all of your generated features
"sites/all/modules/patched" - if for some reason you need to patch a contrib module drop it in here with the patch and some notes so you will know how to update the module later.

So to answer your question directly. You should store features inside the "sites/all/modules" directory.

Edit:
This question inspired me to write a blog post on my company blog to expound on the strategy above a little further. Check it out at [clikfocus.com](http://clikfocus.com/blog/drupal-developer-tip-where-add-drupal-modules)

Comment: Oh and make sure your feature and module don't have the same name. I like to name my features with some added info like "googlemaps_settings" or "blog_post_content_type"